# Optimizing Function with No Critical Points

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, economics

I've been stuck on a profit maximization problem. The question is as follows: Find the optimal ratio of capital per worker for the following profit function:$$\pi (K,L) = 10Y(K,L) -wL-rK  $$
where $w = 4,r=8 $ and $Y(K,L)= 2L^{1/5}K^{4/5}$. Also, K stands for capital and L for labor.

I've taken the partials with respect to both K and L and found that there's no critical point. How else could I maximize this function?

Comment: Have you written the exercise word by word?

Comment: Your variables $K$ and $L$ are probably lower- and upper-bounded. If the solution is not a stationary point, it is on the boundary of the feasible set.

Comment: There's no problem finding a stationary point for this problem. Just set $\pi^{'}_L=0, \pi^{'}_K=0$, and the solution follows immediately. If you were unable to get a solution maybe there is a problem with your derivation

Comment: You are asked to find optimal capital-to-labor ratio not to find the optimal amount of capital and labor. So this question has a well-defined answer.